# Android: How to launch emulator from command line?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit) and Android Studio 2.3.

My Android emulator is located in folder:

d:\Programs\Android\avd.android\avd\Nexus_4_4.avd\

Suppose I'm in folder **D:\temp**.

How from folder **D:\temp** I can launch my emulator (from command line of pc)?

Comment: u use terminal of android studio or cmd of your pc?

Comment: I use cmd of my pc

Comment: cd .. => cd d:\Programs => cd d:\Programs\Android => cd d:\Programs\Android\avd.android =>  d:\Programs\Android\avd.android\avd\Nexus_4_4.avd   after that launch avd from android launch avd cmd

Comment: u can not able to start emulator ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Open command prompt anywhere and use the following command

- To get the list of available emulator

  `emulator -list-avds`
- To open a emulator

  `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23`

Comment: This only works when you are inside $ANDROID_HOME/tools directory on MAC, otherwise you get "Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib" error.

Comment: How to close the cmd that ran the command without closing the emulator with it?

Comment: `C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` on Windows unless you've added this to your PATH

Answer (score 25):

I could only successfully run the command from the tools folder (Windows 10):

```
cd %ANDROID_HOME%/tools
```

To get the list of available virtual devices:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

To run it:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24
```

You can then put this at a .bat file:

```
cd %ANDROID_HOME%/tools
emulator -avd YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE_ID
```

Comment: Note that android home is (on windows): `/Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/` alternatively you can add `/Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/tools/` to environment variables path and you can call `emulator` from anywhere

Comment: I guess this is one of the best answer, i use this one and works like charm, thank you

Comment: `cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools` for Mac users.

Answer (score 9):

Step for :

1. Copy this cd C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator from your system
2. Paste this on System Variable Path Setting.
3. List available emulators: emulator -list-avds
4. Start the emulator: emulator -avd {myEmulator}

Comment: Most appropriate way to run emulator in windows 10. It is annoying to go to the folder every time and run this command. So adding the path to system variable then running this command from anywhere is appropriate way to run emulator. Thanks

Comment: This is what helped me and seems to be the most current method of achieving this. Thank you!

Comment: one can use `%userprofile%` to expand user path : `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers helped me on a windows 10 machine. This is what a window user needs to do:

1. Go to the emulator folder: `cd C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
2. List available emulators: `emulator -list-avds`
3. Start the emulator: `emulator -avd {myEmulator}`

Answer (score 5):

**For WINDOWS only**

**1**. first step to locate your AppData in your user folder if its hidden then in file-mangaer navigate to view-hidden items(check mark)

`cd C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\android\sdk\emulator`
**2**. second step is to see avd(android virtual devices) available
`emulator -list-avds`
**3**. Third steo is to launch avd
`emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29`

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command in cmd:

1. `Cd C:\Users\Username\Appdata\local\Android\Sdk\Emulator`
2. `.\emulator -avd Andro (Emulator Name)`

You can make a shortcut by using a bat file.
Step 1 - Save the Path C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator in Environment variable.
Step 2 - Then make a .bat file and write the command
emaulator -avd (Emaulator Name)

Comment: When running the bat file the cmd stays open, if I try to close it, it closes the emulator too. Is there away to end cmd when it finishes it's job?

Comment: I don't have any android folder in local folder

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows Users:**

- Open CMD Then 
  First Locate your emulator folder directory

  `cd c:\Users\<Your name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
  emulator.exe -list-avds
  emulator.exe -avd emulator-name or emulator-Id`

That's It. you are done.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, open Terminal and run below commands -

1. Navigate to the emulator folder directory(where SDK is installed). In my case -

   `$ cd /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`
2. Then check for available emulators -

   `$ ./emulator -list-avds`
3. And finally -

   `$ ./emulator -avd **nameofthedevice**  -netdelay none -netspeed full`

Answer (score 2):

**Simple steps i followed :**

1. cd `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/`
2. `./emulator -list-avds`
3. Pick one of your available emulator name and run `./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24`

Answer (score 1):

Emulator can also be opened from here

1. Open the location **C:\Users{User_Name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools**
2. Now, open **cmd** from the current location.
3. Type the command **emulator.exe -avd {NameOfYourEmulator}**

This worked for me in Windows 10.

To know the list of emulators. Use the command 
**emulator -list-avds**

Comment: This is only an adaption from the prior answer. Anything new you'd like to add?

Comment: please note that you can also launch emulator from **sdk/tools**. when **SDK/emulator** not works in some exceptional cases.

Comment: How to set a default emulator?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy emulator.exe file location and paste that in global environment variable to access globaly in your system above all may be worked before but in 2020 emulator.exe is in diffrent folder

   C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\emulator

for me it was

```
C:\Users\sachin\AppData\Local\Android\emulator
```

2.simply run in terminal

```
emulator -list-avds

emulator -avd {emulator name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's Fast and no need append to syspath:

Run "Run" <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and put

```
cmd /K "cd C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator&&emulator @{device_name}"
```

change `{username}` to your username and `{device_name}` to your device name

Answer (score -1):

**1**. first step to locate your AppData in your user folder if its hidden then in file-mangaer navigate to view-hidden items(check mark)

`cd C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\android\sdk\emulator`
**2**. second step is to see avd(android virtual devices) available
`emulator -list-avds`
**3**. Third steo is to launch avd
`emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29`

Comment: can you please answer only once?